# How to get Gallery focus position

Tags: android, xamarin, position

I'm playing with Xamarin Gallery. Wish to get the focus position from time to time.

When reach 1 seconds it will go to `OnTimedEvent`, here the code

```
 System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
 timer.Interval = 1000;
 timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
 timer.Enabled = true;
```

On the OnTimedEvent i would like to get the focus position;

```
 private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
     int position = gallery.SelectedItemPosition();
 }
```

Hope someone can help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it already. I forget that we can use `ToString()` to get the data.

Here the code :

```
int position;
int.TryParse(gallery.SelectedItemPosition.ToString(), out position);
```

Sorry that i'm new in Xamarin Android. Thanks for view.